# If input is required add class to a div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to a div if an input has `required=required` but cannot seem to get this to work.

Part of my form:

```
<form id="myform">
<div id="yourname" class="yournamelabel">
    <label>What is your name?</label>
</div>

<div class="js-form-item">
<input type="text" id="enter-your-name" name="your_name" value="" 
class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true">
</div>
</form>
```

And my script:

```
$('[required="required"]').closest('.yournamelabel').addClass('required');
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/penone/wmxj4sth/2/)

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/35r2w4dL/, btw no need to use `required="required"` just use `required`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen if that solves the issue, and you are not expecting this question to be closed as a duplicate, why not make an answer?

Comment: Thanks. This was the solution I needed.

Comment: @Taplar Because sometimes I feel it's more a quick fix of an error, rather than a new "solution" and a duplicate might now help the op to understand what is wrong.

Comment: closest selects parents, that element is a sibling of a parent

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your use of `.closest`. closest travels up the DOM tree, and because yournamelabel is not a parent of the input `closest` doesn't find it.

Changing your html to the following will fix the problem

```
<form id="myform">
    <div id="yourname" class="yournamelabel">
        <label>What is your name?</label>
        <div class="js-form-item">
            <input type="text" id="enter-your-name" name="your_name" value="" 
             class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yghjfp32/

Comment: Please include the logic from the fiddle *in the answer*

Comment: @Taplar the logic is unchanged from the original question, why bother

Comment: Because the fiddle can go dead and then the solution becomes completely worthless to future readers.  And it forces people to go to a third party snippet site to get the full answer, when the same thing can be done with an onsite snippet with clicking the `<>` button or hitting Ctrl+M

Comment: but the js is unchanged... so even if the fiddle dies my answer still contains a working solution to the question, the fiddle doesn't contain any information not in either the question or my answer.

Comment: If that's the case, why include it at all?  But I still still stand by my point.  Answers are intended to be self contained.

Answer (score 0):

The closest method looks at the element itself and its parents. The element you are looking for is not a parent, it is a sibling of the input's parent. So that means it is going to require you do two selections to get to it.

```js
$('[required="required"]')
  .parent()  // grab the div around the input
    .prev('.yournamelabel')  // looks at the previous sibling
      .addClass('required');  // add your class
```

```css
div.required {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <div id="yourname" class="yournamelabel">
    <label>What is your name?</label>
  </div>

  <div class="js-form-item">
    <input type="text" id="enter-your-name" name="your_name" value="" class="form-text required" required="required" aria-required="true">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change your structure you could take advantage of the for property for labels.

```
 <label for="enter-your-name">What is your name?</label>
```

in addition required is just required it is not required="required"

here is a fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/e08drsh5/

```
$('input').filter('[required]').each(function(){
    var $element = $(this)

    if ($element.val() == '') {
        var $label = $("label[for='"+this.id+"']")
        $label.addClass('required')   
    }
});
```